# Problem circle with zoom level

Tags: openlayers-2

when I zoom level 16  and over I have two circle segments, I don't know if it's normal (*projection*) or a bug.

Have you an idea ?

Openlayers : **2.13.1**
Problem With Chrome, IE and Firefox

formula circle

```
function CircleMax(radius)
{
var pointsCircle = [];      
var side = 160; 
var angle;
var projectedLonLat, geometryPoint;
var points = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < side; i++)
{
    angle = (i * 360 / side) + side;
    projectedLonLat = OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty(centerCircle, angle, radius);
    projectedLonLat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));            
    geometryPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(projectedLonLat.lon, projectedLonLat.lat);
    pointsCircle.push(geometryPoint);
}
var layerCircleStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);      
var style_poly = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, layerCircleStyle);  
style_poly.strokeColor = "red";
style_poly.fillColor = "transparent";
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointsCircle);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]),{},style_poly);
circleMaxLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
```

}

Zoom level 6

[image: Zoom le 6]

Zoom level 16 and over
[image: image description here]